# Angular subscribe to login service and get special field from logged in user

Tags: angular, angular-observable

I've got boolean field in user model and I need to open a modal window on the login page right after the user pressed *submit* and got info from server after I checked user.user_on_test field and open modal only if it's true. Can you please help me to extract this info from response?

This is my user.service

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class UserService extends BaseService {
      protected API_PATH: string;

      constructor( protected _http: HttpClient ) {
       super( _http );
       this.API_PATH += '/rest-auth';
       this.getUserData().subscribe();
      }

      private _user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject( null );

      get user(): Observable<User> {
        return this._user.asObservable();
      }

      set user( user ) {
       if ( <User>user ) {
        this._user.next( new User( user ) );
        localStorage.setItem( 'active', ( <User>user)
          .is_active.toString() );
        localStorage.setItem( 'superuser', ( <User>user)
          .is_superuser.toString() );
        localStorage.setItem( 'user_on_test', ( <User>user)
          .user_on_test.toString() );
        } else {
        this._user.next( null );
          localStorage.removeItem( 'active' );
          localStorage.removeItem( 'superuser' );
          localStorage.removeItem( 'user_on_test');
         }
       }

     public login( user: User ): Observable<any> {
      return Observable.concat(
       this.request( {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': '/login/',
        'body': {
          username: user.username,
          password: user.password
        }
       } ),
       this.getUserData()
      );
     }
```

and login.component:

```js
    login() {
      this.errorMsg = '';
      this._authService.login( this.user )
        .takeUntil( this.destroy$).subscribe(
        (response) => {
        if (this._authService.user) {
        // here I need to check user.user_on_test
          alert('this user is on test server!');
        }
        if ( this.redirect ) {
          const url = this._route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] ||'/';
          this._router.navigate( [ url ] );
        }
      },
      ( rejection ) => {
        if ( rejection && rejection.hasOwnProperty( 'error' ) && 
       rejection.error.non_field_errors ) {
          for (const error in rejection.error.non_field_errors) {
            if (rejection.error.non_field_errors.hasOwnProperty(error)) {
              this.errorMsg = rejection.error.non_field_errors[error];
            }
          }
        }
      });
      }
```

Comment: Here is the getUserData():                                                
    'getUserData(): Observable<any> {
      return this.request( {
      'url': '/user/'
     } ).do(
       ( user ) => {
         if ( user ) {
           this.user = user;
        }
      }
      ).catch(
       ( rejection ) => {
        this.user = null;
         return Observable.throw( rejection );
       }
      );
     }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say as `public login(user: User)` has a return type of `Observable<any>`.

Assuming the API call returns a `User`, which would make the method return type `Observable<User>` the code should look something like this:

```
this._authService.login(this.user)
    .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    .subscribe(
    (response: User) => {
        if(response.user_on_test) {
             // open the modal
        }
    },
    {
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say without having the code of "getUserData", neither an example of response of the login request.

My guess for now is you could do something like that :

```
const user = this._authService.user;

if (user && user.user_on_test) {
  alert('this user is on test server!');
}
```

Hope that helps